# Solution for Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solution for the differential equation

$$\Big[\frac{dy}{dx} + y\Big] = (\sin x)/x$$

Got integral factor $e^x$
After that I'm unable to solve it

Comment: The integral which I am getting is $\int \frac{e^x \sin x}{x} dx$ which doesn't seem to have closed form.

Comment: I'm also thinking so..... but waiting for answers

Comment: Thanks replying brother

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(x)%2By(x)%3Dsin(x)%2Fx no closed form in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Thanks brother ur answer is helpful